# Azure Service bus queue getting deleted unexpectedly

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

We experienced that our Azure service bus queue got deleted automatically, we had to create it again. The value for Auto Delete on Idle has max number of days hence it is not related to this value.

We are using standard pricing tier for Service Bus namespace. Also, our queue names are GUIDs if that matter.

Could anyone please suggest?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you provide us a code stack trace of where the bus queue is being deleted? What coding language are you using to provoke the bus queue? if applicable, what framework?

Comment: If you don't specify Auto Delete period, the queue would not just get deleted, something has triggered that deletion. If you haven't talked to Azure support, you should do that. You will not get a reason for deletion of your queue on a public forum since that information is internal to the service. And only service provider can share that information with you.